# Why am I getting a DatabaseObjectNotClosedException with OrmLite under Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite

I get a `android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here` when starting a new `Activity` using OrmLite.

I'm not using any `Cursor`s myself, so it must be the low level code that ORMLite uses. Not sure what the relevant code would be here, but basically I'm using Query/DeleteBuilders with 2 Dao objects usually inside a transaction manager. Minimal example that leads to the problem (exception handling removed):

```
return new TransactionManager(connectionSource).callInTransaction(new Callable<List<ConversionData>>() {
    public List<ConversionData> call() throws Exception {
        QueryBuilder<ConversionData, Date> builder = getDataDao().queryBuilder();
        builder.orderBy("date", /* desc */ true);
        return builder.query();
    }
});
```

Since neither the Dao nor the Builders have any close methods I'm not sure where exactly I should actually close.

There's a close method in my `Activity` that extends `OrmLiteBaseActivity`, but then how would I open it again when I return from the other activity?

Comment: @Gray `ormlite-android-4.39`, which I just see isn't the latest anymore - will update and see if that's the reason. But generally I think it's more likely that I missed something (first project with it) with the API than assuming the bug is in the library. Will check if the newer version helps.

Comment: Don't bother @Voo.  You are close enough.  Are you sure that if you remove the above code the problem goes away?  How about trying to do a `query()` and then taking the first from the resulting `List`.  Does that remove the error?

Comment: @Gray I've reduced it to a pretty minimal example that shows the problem - basically I'm doing the minor bookkeeping necessary for the activity to startup at all (nothing with any DB, just setting some dummy data into variables and initializing the layout), then call the listed code and then start a new activity which causes the error to appear.

Comment: Can you post the code on http://pastebin.com/ or something @Voo?  Sounds to me that you are not initializing things right somehow.

Comment: @Gray I've reduced it quite succinctly I think, see [here](http://pastebin.com/NiPRdkM1), apart from the 2 helper classes (just some POJOs with annotations) that's all the code that's called in my project. No SSCCE because I hope the error will be obvious to someone with experience, but if it's not I'll create one. Note that querying the db works fine and there are no errors as long as I don't start a new activity.

Comment: Can you try it without the `TransactionManager` @Voo?  THere's no need for it but I wonder if it is confusing things.

Comment: @Gray Actually just added it in an attempt to see if that would help (because it was the only part without one). The original code is what's now in the Callable (1:1 copy), and no it doesn't make any difference. Also since I forgot that so far: The actual exception happens in `finalize` in `SQLiteCursor`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10413/discussion-between-gray-and-voo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after some back and forth, this turned out to be a problem with a data iterator on a lazy collection that was not being closed.  @Voo was doing something like the following:

```
for (ConversionRate rate : conversionRates) { 
    if (rate.getCurrency().equals(curr)) 
        // you can't do this because otherwise the iterator won't be closed
        return rate; 
}
```

This problem happens once and a while.  The [documentation for iterators](http://ormlite.com/docs/iterator) is explicit about it.  To quote:

> NOTE: you must page through all items for the iterator to close the underlying SQL object. If you don't go all of the way, the garbage collector will close the SQL statement some time later which is considered bad form. See the wrapped iterable below.

The issue with [lazy collections](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/LazyForeignCollection.html) is also documented:

> WARNING: Most likely for(;;) loops should not be used here since we need to be careful about closing the iterator.

To debug this problem, we first turned the lazy loaded collection into an eager one with `@ForeignCollection(eager = true)`.  That removed the problem indicating that it probably was a improper break out of a `for` loop or some other bad pattern.

Good lesson for others.

Comment: Doesn't the problem go away if you allow the iterator to iterate through all instances, while you save the instance you need, and return it in the end?

Comment: Yes @Christine you are correct.  But in this case (like many) once you find the item you are looking for, you don't want to have to do more IO if you don't have to.  try / finally is always a good idea anyway.